# HTTP code 500 api error for container connecting to rabbitmq container using pika

Tags: python-3.x, pika, python-pika

I am managing 5 docker containers using a docker-compose.yml.

The container functions are:

- message producer - The message producer code is wrapped up in a class and 45 instances are created in 45 threads
- rabbitmq container - This is the rabbitmq:latest image to queue the messages produced
- message receiver - The message receiver code is wrapped up in a class and 90 instances are created in 90 threads. The callback function processes the messages in the rabbitmq container and writes the results to the database container. The callback includes basic_ack:

  ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
- Database container - This is the centurylink/mysql:latest image
- Django site - Connected to database container and used to query the contents of the database

The connection to the rabbitmq container is created in the same way using the same parameters in both the producer and the receiver:

```
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(host=TARGET_QUEUE_NAME,
            port=5672,
            heartbeat_interval=0,
            backpressure_detection=True,
             blocked_connection_timeout=10))
```

Initially, the process works correctly and the records are visibly updating as expected if you refresh the Django site. At some point after a few minutes docker slows down and eventually grinds to a halt and refreshing the django page take 20+ seconds. The message producer eventually exits with the error:

> message_producer_1     | Killed
>
> Unexpected API error for this_project_ message_producer_1 (HTTP code
>   500) Response body: A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I'm not sure where to start finding/solving the issue here. The fact that everything works initially and then breaks makes me think that its probably due to the message queue size or resources available to the containers but I don't know how to test this.

Any help?

Comment: Have you checked various log files? Do you have monitoring in place? It appears like you're overloading your environment but without monitoring there's no proof.

Comment: I'm using the docker extension in vscode and the docker logs accessible by right clicking the container just say exactly what I put in the post - the http code 500 error. Actually docker itself blocks many times and until I restart docker and the container I can't access the logs...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I entered the docker desktop settings and saw the place where you can limit the resources available for the machine. I increased it a a bunch (no. of cpu's, memory and swap) and it's been running fine. I'm not sure if I over allocated (8 cpu's 14gb memory, 4gb swap) I have no idea how to benchmark how much I need, but it is working. No crash.